# What is a good way to reclaim counter space from an inbuilt draining board?

Tags: kitchens, kitchen-sink, kitchen-counters, countertops

My sink has an inbuilt draining board like this.

[image]

The draining board is useless to me because I also have a dishwasher, which drains the dishes after they are washed. Small jobs get washed and dried by hand and then put away immediately.

The problem is the draining board takes up valuable counter space. I would rather have just more counter where the board is. But short of replacing the entire counter top this will not happen.

Is there a good way to turn the drainer space into usable countertop? I could of course slap a chopping board on it but the chopping board will wobble on the metal surface. What is the next easiest solution?

Comment: Uh...Just put things on it...it's a slightly ridged metal countertop. You're overcomplicating this. You won't even need a trivet for hot things!

Comment: @Ecnerwal But the things will be *gasp* wobbly!

Comment: Big enough chopping board to reach all the way from the front of the counter to the back, then...completely spanning the drainboard area.

Comment: + for Ecnerwal's cutting board.  Put some nylon feet on it and you can stand it behind the faucet to dry after you wash it.  Water draining off will drain into the sink thanks to that nice little lip your sink has.

Comment: I’d put in a nice big sink instead, but that also sacrifices counter space.

Comment: I've seen folks with chopping boards to cover the sink they are not using at the moment, too, @JonCuster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I really don't think you need to do anything to this area to use it as countertop. But if you insist:

Big enough chopping board to reach all the way from the front of the counter to the back...

...completely spanning the drainboard area.

Put feet on it to raise it up a bit if that seems needed for stability.